# Error: Unable to find @SpringBootConfiguration when doing @WebMvcTest for Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test

I am testing my controller given below

```
@Controller
public class MasterController {

@GetMapping("/")
public String goLoginPage(){
    return "index";
}
}
```

I am following [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/) Spring documentation to test my controller.
Now, I want to test my controller by just instantiating the web layer and not the whole Spring context as given in the documentation. Below is my code for the same.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
public class MasterControllerTestWithWebLayer {

@Autowired
MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
MasterController masterController;


@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
}

@Test
public void testLoginHome() throws Exception{
    mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(view().name("index"));
}

}
```

When I run this test I get the error `Unable to find @SpringBootConfiguration,...etc`. But I am confused why it is asking for Spring configuration when we do not want it to instantiate it but want to use only the web layer. Kindly point me to the right direction what is happening here. And also how to fix this. Thanks

Comment: try with this @WebMvcTest(controllers = MasterController.class). And remove this 
@Autowired
MasterController masterController;

Comment: @pvpkiran okay, that would work, but why not like this?

Comment: Do you have any other dependencies in your controller. For example like a Service class or something?

Comment: @pvpkiran No, And guess what even if I give the controller name in `@WebMvcTest` still it is not working?

Comment: Try putting @SpringBootTest(classes = YourSpringBootClassName.class) on top of MasterControllerTestWithWebLayer class

Answer (score 136, accepted):

So here is the solution:

The [documentation on detecting test configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config) says:

> The search algorithm works up from the package that contains the test until it finds a @SpringBootApplication or @SpringBootConfiguration annotated class. As long as you’ve structure your code in a sensible way your main configuration is usually found.

So the `@SpringBootApplication` class should be higher in the package hierarchy than the test class e.g if test class is in package `com.zerosolutions.controller` then `@SpringBootApplication` class should be in a package higher than `com.zerosolutions.controller` package i.e `com.zerosolutions` or  `com`.

**Problem**

But in case the `@SpringBootApplication` class is at the same level as test class it won't be able to find it i.e `com.zerosolutions.general`. In this case you'll get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test

**Solution**

If you are running an integrated test, you can explicitly mention the `@SpringBootApplication` class like this

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes={SpringBootApp.class})
```

But if you want to do unit testing of a controller you don't need to fire up the whole Spring context. You can rather replace `@SpringBootTest` with `@WebMvcTest(MasterController.class)`. This will instantiate only the web layer with `MasterController` and not the whole Spring context.

**Problem**

But the problem is you will again run into the error we faced earlier:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test

And `@WebMvtTest` does not have a `classes` attribute like `@SpringBootTest` to explicitly mention the `@SpringBootApplication` class.
So there are two solutions to this.

**Solution**

**First**: Move your application class to a package higher than the test class i.e `com.zerosolutions` or `com` package.

**Second**: Mention your `@SpringBootApplication` class explicitly like below

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(MasterController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={SpringBootApp.class})
```

Hope that clears the Spring Test Configuration confusion. Thanks

Comment: your answer helped  me in figuring out issue that i had spent hrs figuring out. Test class not being able to find main boot application class though it appeared to be under same same package  but in main and test folders. once i specifically pointed the main application class using annotation @SpringBootTest(classes=...) things started worked.

Comment: This helped me. In my case, my test was a Kotlin class placed in a file without any `package` declaration. It happened due to some copy pasting and moving stuff around. Intellij's Kotlin plugin never warned me about a misplaced class.

Comment: great answer bang on target helped me get an understanding of the issue and solution as well !

Comment: Perfectly explained!

Answer (score 33):

If your Application.java class (in src/main/java) is located under

`com.A.B`

Your test class ApplicationTest.java (in src/test/java) need to be under

`com.A.B` or `com.A.B.C` or `com.A.B.C.D`

You will get this error if the test class is located under the following packages

`com.A` or `com.A.C` or `com.A.D`

In Spring boot 
THE GENERAL RULE IS **TEST CLASS PACKAGE NAME NEED TO START WITH THE PACKAGE NAME OF THE JAVA CLASS PACKAGE THAT IS GOING TO BE TESTED**

Comment: in my project I have my Application.class located in src/main/java/com/company/example and my test class ApplicationTest.java located in src/test/java/com/company/example . Tests execution (mvn test) still throws IllegalStateException. Did I misunderstood something from your explanation? I thought that spring boot is able to find the application class automatically with this setup.

Comment: Yes Spring Boot test class should be in the same package of the main class.

Comment: Amazing answer!It took me many hours to figure it out!Thanks

Answer (score 2):

check if src/test/java has same package name as the main class package.
src/test/java/com/example/abc is same as src/test/java/com/example/abc

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, and found that when I had generated the project my pom.xml showed my groupId as com.example rather than with my actual domain:
`<groupId>com.example</groupId>`
I corrected the pom.xml to be:
`<groupId>com.mydomain</groupId>`
Next, I changed the file structure from:
`src/test/java/com/example` to `src/test/java/com/mydomain`
Last, I had to update the package declaration inside my
`SampleProjectApplicationTest.java`
file to match the correct file structure. Once that was all in place, the tests worked fine.

I am not sure how I ended up with com.example where the rest of my project was correct, but the fix was that simple in my case.

Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the Test package name with the main Application class package name.

Example:- `package com.kotlin.dealerMainApplication` this is my main app package name so, I will put the same name in my Test package

This worked for me !