# Spring Boot multiple module test Autowiring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, spring-boot-configuration

I have a multiple module project with structure:

```
app/
  build.gradle
  settings.gradle
  app-web/
    src/main/java/example/
      Application.java
  app-repository/
    src/main/java/example/
      CustomerRepository.java
      Customer.java
    src/test/java/example/
      CustomerRepositoryTest
```

With Application Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```

With Repository

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {
}
```

And Repository Test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class CustomerRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void shouldSave() {
        // When
        final Customer saved = repository.save(new Customer());

        // Then
        assertThat(saved.getID()).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

Now when I run this test I get the error:

> Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use
>   @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test

This doesnt appear when I have the Application class in my repository module but I need them to be seperated out. What's the best way to get this to work?

If it helps my Spring dependencies are:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
compile("com.h2database:h2")
testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
```

Using the plugin `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.8.RELEASE`

Comment: Try moving all classes besides the `Application` (including the test)  to a separate package (e.g. `src/main/java/example/subpackage`). I recall there is a problem with component scan when `@SpringBootApplication` and `@SpringBootTest` are in the same package. I think it's a know issue, cannot find the reference though

Comment: @jannis I still get the same error :( Is there a way I can tell the test how to configure it without even having an `Application` class?

Comment: @jannis I have a feeling `@SpringBootTest` is intended for the REST layer so maybe its to do with that

Comment: Swapping out the `@SpringBootTest` for `@EnableAutoConfiguration` gets the test green but I couldnt say why

Comment: Mentioned reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43517967/4494577

Comment: @jannis Looks useful thanks, didnt realise about the package hierachy issue

Answer (score 0):

It seems package hierarchy problem. You have to include sub projects `(app-web & app-repository)` to resources section in Gradle. I had same issue in my maven problem and resolved by adding to resources section. I'm not good in gradle and found a link: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_resources