# Spring boot test controllers when no app class present

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test-mvc

So i have a multi maven module project, with a module for controllers and a module that contains the spring boot start up application class.

myApp
  - deployment    (module)
  - controllers   (module)

In the controllers module i want to be able to test them using mockMvc

however when i run it i get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test
```

what i want to do is still be able to test this, can i create an test application and use that?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(Controller.class)
@ActiveProfiles(Constants.TEST)
public class ControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  public void contextLoads() {
    assertNotNull(mockMvc);
  }

}
```

Comment: You can create a dedicated SpringBootApplication just like the normal class have the main function under your module test package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a "test config" class inside your test package like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestConfig {

}
```

I'm using this a proach for custom repository or services libe that I need to test

than you can annotate your class with

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
```

and than you can

```
@Autowired
protected MockMvc mockMvc;
```

and all the other stuff you need.

hope this helps

Comment: Thats kinda works, but i still want to be able to use WebMvcTest.. is there anything else other than SpringBootTest i can use instead... to only load controllers.

Comment: no i meant i want to use WebMvcTest instead of SpringBootTest to start the app up.

Comment: no then I think you can't, is matter of component scan, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43515279/error-unable-to-find-springbootconfiguration-when-doing-webmvctest-for-spring

Comment: or directly https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config

Comment: yes i can by placing the TestConfig in the same package as the test classes. it then was picked up. :)

Comment: you are right, I don't know why I keep mixing your question with the @SpringBoot Test :D